# Meta Meta Privilege

Tags: support, meta, privileges, privileges-page

I just took a look at meta today and noticed something weird in the meta privileges. If you look at the meta privilege list, you can see that at [5 rep you can participate in meta](https://meta.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/participate-in-meta). I know that there is no meta for meta, and the link they give you in the privilege page leads you to meta.stackexchange.com, right where you started. Why do they have this privilege? I have a feeling that this is a bad recursive joke. You must be  member of meta to get the privilege of being a member of meta! :)

[image: meta]

Comment: meta.stackoverflow.com is ... special.

Comment: @MartijnPieters special how? Special as in 'smart' special, or that *other* kind of special?

Comment: @RichardJ.RossIII Yes.

Comment: This post was created before the post that this post is marked a duplicate of, so if anything, that post is the duplicate, not this one.  Not a big deal to me though.

Comment: Eh, @Joshua people here tend to close earlier questions as dupes of older ones.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The privilege pages on MSE are the master wikis for all the privilege pages across the network. When they are edited, the privilege pages across the network are (eventually) updated.

With that in mind, the privilege for participating in meta is listed on the page to make it accessible and editable.

It probably should say "1 rep" though. MSE need only 1 rep for meta participation (unlike the other metas).

Comment: +1 The required reputation for this privilege should be droped to 1 on meta.so