# Remove Meta Privilege for MSE (only)

Tags: feature-request, status-declined, meta, privileges

What I am asking here is to **please remove the privilege to participate in Meta for MSE.**

This privilege is literally useless. You can't really have a meta site for a meta site. There's no Meta.Meta.SE here or any other SE site out there: Meta.SE covers for every site in SE, including itself.

When users find out that you don't really get anything new, it's kinda sad for those people. There is no use for it except just to be there and fill up the space between the first and third privilege.
Privileges should be shown only if you earn something new, and this privilege to participate in the meta isn't new because it's where you report problems in all of SE, including Meta.SE.

So please remove the privilege to participate in meta just for Meta.SE.

This is not a dupe as this is a feature-request to remove it, not support on why it is there.

Comment: Shouldn't reduce ads be removed by the same logic since there are no ads to reduce?

Comment: to much meta, I'm out...

Comment: possible duplicate of [Meta Meta Privilege](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/196998/meta-meta-privilege)

Comment: @psubsee2003 While technically true, redirecting future readers to a post about meta.SO (pre-split) is going to be more confusing than helpful.

Comment: @pizza then edit the other post.... the answers are virtually identical.  I see no reason to keep duplicates because of the MSO v MSE split

Comment: @psubsee2003 I voted to close the 2013 post as a duplicate of this one.

Comment: It's a dupe war between pizza and psubee2003! Who will emerge the victor!?

Comment: Or, we could leave a *support* question open with answers providing useful information based on it being a support question, and *also leave this one open* (I know, scary suggestion) because it is a *feature-request* asking for something to be implemented. 1) "How does **X** work" and 2) "Please remove/change **X**" are not duplicates of each other.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

*All* privileges exist here on Meta because Meta serves as the global hub for all the privilege pages across the network. This is where the staff can edit the master pages and the changes eventually get pushed out across the network.

**Side Note:** Regular users could suggest edits to these pages at one point too, but that ability has since been removed.

Comment: You could reduce the privilege to 1 rep and hide it in the privileges display, then nobody on Meta itself would notice it but it would still exist.

Comment: @Ani could you mark as status declined or deffered etc?