# Remove Reduce Ads Privilege for MSE (only)

Tags: feature-request, privileges

Note: Inspriation comes from Robert Longson from his comment on this [question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/254054/remove-meta-privilege-for-mse-only).

I am asking that the privilege to see less ads be removed from MSE only.

Why? Because there aren't any ads in MSE. With no ads here, you can't really see a negative amount of ads here or see any at all. Like the linked question said, the users who find out that the privilege is useless will be kinda sad. Privileges should be new and this isn't new or going to give users something new.

So can we remove the privilege to see less ads in Meta.SE only?

Comment: Should this be considered a bug? [Does the reduced advertising privilege exist on non-trilogy sites that carry ads?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/246563/248072)